# Difficulty in getting data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

As a self-taught (poorly) PHP coder, I have exhausted all the trial-and-error possibilities so I humbly ask your help for a small problem I have been having while coding a community online "bidding" game.

I have two tables in my DB - one, called DCO_sponsors, listing a list of IDs, an associated amount of (virtual!) money, an availability counter and (if they are already associated with a team), the team's id.

Structure: id, amount, available, team_id

The second table, DCO_bids, lists the team's "bids" to clinch the above mentioned sponsors. It includes a bid id, the team id, a "part_b" which in this case is the sponsor id (the same table is used by other processes), a concept field where the kind of bid is described (e.g. "sponsorship") and finally two fields for the bid amount and the current status (A for active, W for waiting/pending, etc).

Structure: id, team_id, part_b, concept, bid, status

What I want to achieve is the site to show me (the admin) a list of all the sponsors in the DCO_sponsors table, ordered by the amount, and next to it the team_id of the team which bid the highest for it (teams only get four "sponsors" and get the highest grossing first, so it's important I see them in order of amount).

The code I produced, and that I hoped it would work, is as follows:

```
            echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th width=30>Id</th><th width=100>Amount</th><th width=220>Team</th><th width=100>Offer</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>";

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT id, amount FROM DCO_sponsors WHERE available='1' ORDER BY amount DESC", $CONNECTW);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($data))
        {
            $sp_id = "$row[0]";
            $sp_amount = number_format($row[1]);

            $teamdata = mysql_query("SELECT team_id, bid FROM DCO_bids WHERE concept='sponsorship' AND part_b='$sp_id' ORDER BY bid DESC", $CONNECTW);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($teamdata))
            {
                $team_id = "$row[0]";
                $team_bid = number_format($row[1]);                     
            }               

            // I call the name of the team from another table

            $teamlabel = mysql_query("SELECT completename FROM DCO_teams WHERE id='$team_id'", $CONNECTW);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($teamdata))
            {
                $teamname = "$row[0]";                      
            }

            echo "<tr><td>$sp_id</td><td>&pound;$sp_amount</td><td>$teamname</td><td>$team_bid</td><td><a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A1&item_id=$item_id'><div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 1 deal with $teamname'></div></a></td><td><a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A2&item_id=$item_id'><div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 2 deal with $teamname'></div></a></td><td><a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A3&item_id=$item_id'><div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 3 deal with $teamname'></div></a></td></tr>";

        }

        echo "</table>";
```

The links in the last cells of the row are tick-boxes linked to actions that modify other tables.

At the moment, the result I get is the list of the sponsors ordered by the amount (as it should be), but the team name appearing alongside it is the same for all rows, it's NOT the one of the highest bidder and the bid amount is NOT the one of the highest bidder but simply the first one to put one in.

I spent the best part of the last three nights trying to work out where I am getting this wrong... I hope you  can help!

Comment: ok, after reading this I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I think I have the basic idea. So, you want `$teamname = "$row[0]";` to return the name with the higest bidder, correct?

Comment: Yes - actually, that would be 
$teamdata = mysql_query("SELECT team_id, bid FROM DCO_bids WHERE concept='sponsorship' AND part_b='$sp_id' ORDER BY bid DESC", $CONNECTW);

$teamname just takes the full name from another table as opposed to just showing the ID number of the team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width=30>Id</th>
    <th width=100>Amount</th>
    <th width=220>Team</th>
    <th width=100>Offer</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
<? $data = mysql_query("SELECT id, amount FROM DCO_sponsors WHERE available='1' ORDER BY amount DESC", $CONNECTW); ?>

<? while($row=mysql_fetch_row($data)):
    $sp_id = $row['id'];
    $sp_amount = number_format($row['amount']);

    $teamdata = mysql_query("SELECT team_id, bid FROM DCO_bids WHERE concept='sponsorship' AND part_b='$sp_id' ORDER BY bid DESC", $CONNECTW);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($teamdata))
    {
        $team_id = $row['id'];
        $team_bid = number_format($row['bid']);                     
    }               

        $teamlabel = mysql_query("SELECT completename FROM DCO_teams WHERE id='$team_id'", $CONNECTW);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($teamlabel))
        {
            $teamname = $row['completename'];                      
        }
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$sp_id;?></td>
      <td>&pound;<?=$sp_amount;?></td>
      <td><?=$teamname;?></td>
      <td><?=$team_bid;?></td>
      <td><a href='<?=$RKP;?>/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A1&item_id=<?=$item_id;?>'>
        <div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 1 deal with <?=$teamname;?>'></div></a></td>
      <td><a href='<?=$RKP;?>/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A2&item_id=<?=$item_id;?>'>
        <div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 2 deal with <?=$teamname;?>'></div></a></td>
      <td><a href='<?=$RKP;?>/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A3&item_id=<?=$item_id;?>'>
        <div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 3 deal with <?=$teamname;?>'></div></a></td>
    </tr>

<? endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Your issue came into play with your last while call.  You were attempting to mysql_fetch_row($teamdata) again instead of $teamlabel.

Also, as a rule, you should just write out any html that doesn't need to be generated by php.  So I broke that stuff out for you.

Comment: Thank you Josh - this fixed the correct team name appearing in the list! However, it is still not the highest bidder name appearing now, but the first one who did the bid (based on id number from the BIDS table I suppose) (and the relative amount).

One step ahead, however :) thanks!

Comment: So in your BID table there is a list of bids which each have a team ID associated to them and a bid amount?  What is the field type for the bid column? Is it possible that the column is formatted incorrectly and is not sorting based on the value of a number, but on some other factor?

Comment: Also, how are the bids and sponsors related?  I'm having trouble piecing together your schema in my mind.  The way you have it set up now, your table is going to first through the list of sponsors, starting with the ones with the highest amount.  For each of those sponsors, it will push out a row for each team that they sponsor and  within that the bids from highest to low.  If you are trying to get the bids to go from High to low no matter which team or sponsor they are related to, you should start out by querying the bid table like you have and working backwards.

Comment: Here is a snippet from the Sponsors table:
http://www.gpvwc.com/storage/images/sponsorstable.JPG

Each ID is a different sponsor and the amount is what they offer.

Here is the bids table:


http://www.gpvwc.com/storage/images/bidstable.JPG

As you can see, sponsor 17 (the 17 in the part_b field) received three bids (from teams 74, 5 and 73). As it is now, the one shown would be the 500k from team 74 as it was the first to be placed (notice the bid id number), while the one that it SHOULD show is the  715k from team 5 as it is the highest.

Comment: This is how the page looks in the end, by the way:
http://www.gpvwc.com/storage/images/list.JPG

Comment: Just to add to it - I truly appreciate your help. Hopefully I can learn something from it - dealing with info from more tables is my weak(est) point!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem - here is the code that works:

```
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th width=30>Id</th><th width=100>Amount</th><th width=220>Team</th><th width=100>Offer</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>";

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, amount FROM DCO_sponsors WHERE available = '1' ORDER BY amount DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $sp_id = $row['id'];
        $sp_amount = $row['amount'];
        $sp_amount = number_format($sp_amount);
        $tQuery = mysql_query("SELECT team_id, bid, id FROM DCO_bids WHERE concept='sponsorship' AND part_b='$sp_id' AND status='W' ORDER BY bid DESC");
        $trow = ' ';
        $trow = mysql_fetch_assoc($tQuery);
        $team_id = $trow['team_id'];
        $team_bid = $trow['bid'];
        $team_bid = number_format($team_bid);
        $item_id = $trow['id'];
        $nquery = mysql_query("SELECT completename FROM DCO_teams WHERE id='$team_id'");
        $nrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($nquery);
        $teamname = $nrow['completename'];


        echo "<tr><td>$sp_id</td><td>&pound;$sp_amount</td><td>$teamname</td><td>&pound;$team_bid</td><td><a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A1&item_id=$item_id'><div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 1 deal with $teamname'></div></a></td><td><a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A2&item_id=$item_id'><div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 2 deal with $teamname'></div></a></td><td><a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Bids_Update.php?op=A3&item_id=$item_id'><div id='IC_Tick' title='Sign Round 3 deal with $teamname'></div></a></td></tr>";
    }

     echo "</table>";
```